# Wrong count of records in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote a below mention query, I need to prepare list in GUI where I need to show the counts of total records, now my records are 119 which is correct but when I apply the count function it becomes 115. I am wondering why it is happening.

```
SELECT distinct E.EMP_CODE,
  a.EMP_ID,
  e.name,
  E.ADHAR_NO,
  a.CURRENT_STATUS,
  D.NAME
FROM ACR a
JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON E.EMP_ID=a.EMP_ID
JOIN DESIGNATION D
ON D.DESIGNATION_ID      =E.DESIGNATION_ID
AND e.EMP_TYPE_ID NOT   IN(02,03,04,06,08)
AND (e.DESIGNATION_ID   IN (23,99)
OR d.DESIGNATION_CLASS IN(1,2))
AND (e.relief_type      IS NULL
OR e.RELIEF_TYPE         = 4)
JOIN REGION R
ON R.REGION_ID=E.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN CIRCLE C
ON C.CIRCLE_ID       =E.CIRCLE_ID
WHERE ACR_FOR_SESSION='2017-2018'
AND E.CIRCLE_ID     IS NULL
AND E.REGION_ID      =1
AND a.CURRENT_STATUS>1
```

total record list is `119`

now after applying count over `DISTINCT E.EMP_CODE`

```
SELECT count(distinct E.EMP_CODE)
FROM ACR a
JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON E.EMP_ID=a.EMP_ID
JOIN DESIGNATION D
ON D.DESIGNATION_ID      =E.DESIGNATION_ID
AND e.EMP_TYPE_ID NOT   IN(02,03,04,06,08)
AND (e.DESIGNATION_ID   IN (23,99)
OR d.DESIGNATION_CLASS IN(1,2))
AND (e.relief_type      IS NULL
OR e.RELIEF_TYPE         = 4)
JOIN REGION R
ON R.REGION_ID=E.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN CIRCLE C
ON C.CIRCLE_ID       =E.CIRCLE_ID
WHERE ACR_FOR_SESSION='2017-2018'
AND E.CIRCLE_ID     IS NULL
AND E.REGION_ID      =1
AND a.CURRENT_STATUS>1

Output: 115 (Wrong)
```

Am I missing something? Kindly suggest me the best solution

Comment: just remove distinct keyword from count

Comment: could be you have some e.emp_code values duplicated ..,eg: an emp_code have more that a rows ..

Comment: yes I do have two records for some employees, but i need to count that employee only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query lists rows that are **distinct in all the columns selected**. The second query counts distinct values in a single column `E.EMP_CODE`.

```
E.EMP_CODE A.EMP_ID ...
1          2        ...
1          3        ...
```

Two distinct rows for the first query, but only one distinct `E.EMP_CODE` for `count`.

Comment: How do I count rows on behalf of a.EMP_Id and e.EMPCODE

Comment: Great, you are the one who exactly identifies the problem, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by , because in your 1st query grouply making distinct so apply same in 2nd query also

```
select sum(cnt)  from
        (
       SELECT count(E.EMP_CODE) as cnt
        FROM ACR a
        JOIN EMPLOYEE E
        ON E.EMP_ID=a.EMP_ID
        JOIN DESIGNATION D
        ON D.DESIGNATION_ID      =E.DESIGNATION_ID
        AND e.EMP_TYPE_ID NOT   IN(02,03,04,06,08)
        AND (e.DESIGNATION_ID   IN (23,99)
        OR d.DESIGNATION_CLASS IN(1,2))
        AND (e.relief_type      IS NULL
        OR e.RELIEF_TYPE         = 4)
        JOIN REGION R
        ON R.REGION_ID=E.REGION_ID
        LEFT JOIN CIRCLE C
        ON C.CIRCLE_ID       =E.CIRCLE_ID
        WHERE ACR_FOR_SESSION='2017-2018'
        AND E.CIRCLE_ID     IS NULL
        AND E.REGION_ID      =1
        AND a.CURRENT_STATUS>1
       group by 
       a.EMP_ID,
      e.name,
      E.ADHAR_NO,
      a.CURRENT_STATUS,
      D.NAME
      ) t
```

Comment: If i remove distinct keyword that it will fetch 140 records

Comment: @user9634982 you can use group by of your 1st query selection list

Comment: Thank you so much, I implement the group by and sum up the count, I got my expected output, I used combined solution from you and Jiri

Comment: @user9634982 if it helps please accept the answer as a so appreciation

Comment: @Zyanul I do appreciate your solution, and one more thing you have really beautiful name Masha Allah

Answer (score 1):

Because there are some row `E.EMP_CODE` the same in `E.EMP_CODE`. when you use `count(distinct E.EMP_CODE)` only remove the same value from `E.EMP_CODE` then get the `COUNT` number

but when you use

```
distinct E.EMP_CODE,
  a.EMP_ID,
  e.name,
  E.ADHAR_NO,
  a.CURRENT_STATUS,
  D.NAME
```

will remove all of those same value.

Here is a sample.

```
CREATE TABLE T(col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50));

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A','B'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A','B1'); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('AB','B3');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8089a/2/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
|------|------|
|    A |   B1 |
|    A |    B |
|   AB |   B3 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1)
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8089a/2/1)**:

```
| COUNT(DISTINCTCOL1) |
|---------------------|
|                   2 |
```

Comment: well explained, its really a helpful for me

Comment: @user9634982 No problem glad to help

Answer (score 0):

could be you have some e.emp_code values duplicated ..,eg: an emp_code have more that a rows

try avoid distinct in you count

```
  SELECT count(E.EMP_CODE)
  FROM ACR a
  JOIN EMPLOYEE E
  ON E.EMP_ID=a.EMP_ID
  JOIN DESIGNATION D
  ON D.DESIGNATION_ID      =E.DESIGNATION_ID
  AND e.EMP_TYPE_ID NOT   IN(02,03,04,06,08)
  AND (e.DESIGNATION_ID   IN (23,99)
  OR d.DESIGNATION_CLASS IN(1,2))
  AND (e.relief_type      IS NULL
  OR e.RELIEF_TYPE         = 4)
  JOIN REGION R
  ON R.REGION_ID=E.REGION_ID
  LEFT JOIN CIRCLE C
  ON C.CIRCLE_ID       =E.CIRCLE_ID
  WHERE ACR_FOR_SESSION='2017-2018'
  AND E.CIRCLE_ID     IS NULL
  AND E.REGION_ID      =1
  AND a.CURRENT_STATUS>1
```

distint count return only the number of differnet value in columns